# Items are not showing in Firebase Analytics

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I am facing issue with Firebase Analytics. I have integrated events in my Android app as per the documentation (https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/measure-ecommerc) and it is sending logs successfully. But I found issue with Firebase Console.
Issue:

1. Items are visible in the DebugView but not showing in Realtime.
2. Items are not showing in Top Events.

Is there any thing we need to take care here? Please help me to get rid of it.

1. Items are visible in the DebugView
   [image]
2. Items are not showing in Top Events
   [image]

Comment: if the firebase integration is done recently then it sometimes takes time to reflect!

Comment: it is working fine in debugView but items are not showing in Top Event and RealTime

Comment: basically it takes time to synchronise

Comment: I found this - https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/47385105/91491665-c2d39b00-e88a-11ea-828d-5eff51c37f4c.png from here - https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/4018